# Suspicious activity has occured on your IP address?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Im getting this error :

> Suspicious activity has occured on your IP address and you have been
>   denied access for another [868] second(s).

Now what i want is to catch this error in my controller and send it like response. Any suggestion how can i catch this error? Im using `Sentinel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
catch (\Cartalyst\Sentinel\Checkpoints\checkThrottlingException $e)
```

replace checkThrottlingException with the correct exception it throws

Comment: where to add this `catch (\Cartalyst\Sentinel\Checkpoints\checkThrottlingException $e)`